# remove duplicated data from two different foreach loops

Tags: php, loops, duplicates

I have two for each loop . Each one is running on a different table

```html
$nores_std="SELECT std_id,std_name FROM student WHERE std_class = '$cl' ";
$nores_q = mysqli_query($link,$nores_std);
foreach ($nores_q as $name_std){
echo $name_std['std_id']; echo '<br>';
}
echo '<br>';
$no_select = "SELECT std_id,std_name FROM selection WHERE std_class = '$cl' ";
$no_select_q = mysqli_query($link,$no_select);
foreach ( $no_select_q as $std_sel){
    echo $std_sel['std_id'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```

The firs result is:

```
**554553**
**554557**
554561
**554566**
554573
**554577**
554581
554582
554587
**554590**
554591
554593
554596
554597
554599
554602
554603
554604
554607
554619
554620
554632
554637
554640
554643
554648
**554549**
```

And the second result is:

```
554566
554577
554549
554590
554553
554557
```

I would like to check for duplication and remove the duplication values, display only the one that are not duplicated in

Comment: Could you just use `SELECT DISTINCT std_id, std_name... ` This is dependent on your data, but I'm hoping your student names and ids are 1:1.

Comment: Join will help me even that the values are not at the same order?

Comment: You should probably fix your data model first of all. It looks like you have student id and name in both tables. Assuming that `student` is supposed to hold the actual student details, and `selection` holds the info which student selected which classes(?), the name should only occur in the first one, but not be repeated redundantly in the second. You should properly JOIN together the info you need instead.

Comment: i have student table and a course selection table, every student is selecting courses from a list , i wold like to display the students that did make a selection yes

Comment: You can solve it with `array_unique` and `array_diff ` but I would re-check you data scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PHP` solution is by [array-diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$nores_std="SELECT std_id,std_name FROM student WHERE std_class = '$cl' ";
$nores_q = mysqli_query($link,$nores_std);
foreach ($nores_q as $name_std){
    $a[] = $name_std['std_id'];
}

$no_select = "SELECT std_id,std_name FROM selection WHERE std_class = '$cl' ";
$no_select_q = mysqli_query($link,$no_select);
foreach ( $no_select_q as $std_sel){
    $b[] = $std_sel['std_id'];
}

$res = array_diff($a, $b);
```

Notice You can used [array-column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to avoid the `foreach` loop

**I would recheck the data scheme** - you may want to get you data differently

Comment: Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\School\class_no_select.php on line 10

Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\School\class_no_select.php on line 14

Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\School\class_no_select.php on line 16 this is the error i get

Comment: @drorshalit added `mysqli_fetch_all` to convert result object to array

Comment: @drorshalit Use the way you did till now to get your values - the main line this answer is the `array_diff`. I edit my post as your way to get the data

Comment: thank you!. i still get the same duplicated values . i wold like to remove compliantly the duplication that match from the array.

Comment: Can you please share arrays `$a` and `$b` before the `array_diff` and the output of the `array_diff`

Comment: @drorshalit I meant also the content of `$res`

Comment: i check my self agile and it works, my problem now is when i change the val for std_id to std_name i can see the duplication :(  what is the dentifrice between number and letters?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to select distinct from the two tables in a single query:

```
SELECT DISINCT std_id, std_name FROM
(
        SELECT std_id, std_name FROM student   WHERE std_class = '$cl'
  UNION SELECT std_id, std_name FROM selection WHERE std_class = '$cl'
) t
```